# Disable "Add this Internet Calendar to Outlook?" warning for ICS attachments

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When opening an .ics attachment in Outlook I always get the following pop-up warning:

> **Add this Internet Calendar to Outlook?**
>
> You should only open calendars from sources you know and trust.

I can bypass it by saving the attachment to file first but I'm hoping there might be a hidden Registry entry for it.

**Is there a way to disable this warning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, really did a lot of search, but seems that there is no specific Registry entry to disable this specific warning pop up. [Similar issues](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-2013-will-not-open-icloud-ics-meeting/4a8cc32c-3408-4024-81e4-1db48e9a4225).

Comment: Yeah, the DisableHyperlinkWarning is active for me already but does something else. Looks like there's no way to toggle this particular one. :|

Comment: Might we indeed could not skip security warnings like that. Outlook may want to avoid possible confusion via this kinds of way.

Comment: True. It's likely to prevent people mistakenly adding calendars while checking attachments. But strange as the entries aren't added until you save. Oh well, the workaround is fine enough. Thanks for looking into this as well.